# How to avoid the textfields in a form to clear out onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form with 4 text fields. When the user clicks on a save button to save the content of these fields the text fields are automatically cleared out. How do I avoid that?

This is my function that runs `onclick`:

```
function saveProblem() {    
    var location = document.getElementById("txtinput_location").value;
    var description = document.getElementById("description").value;
    var importance = document.getElementById("importance").value;
    var type = document.getElementById("problemtype").value;        
    var datetime = new Date();
    var date = "Dato: " + datetime.toLocaleDateString() + " KL: " + datetime.getHours() + ":" + datetime.getMinutes();

    if (location === "" || description === "" || description === "" || importance === "") {
        alert("\nALLE FELTER SKAL UDFYLDES!");
    } else {
        problem_array.push(new Problem(location, description, importance, type, date));
    }

    console.log("OBJECT: " + location + " " + importance + " " + type + " " + description + " " + date);
    console.log("Array lenght: " + problem_array.length);
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that your button is not actually submitting your form? forgetting to put  `type="button"` will make a button inside a `form` tag act as a submit button and send the form. Since nothing in this code sets the values of the fields to '', Id guess this is your real issue

Comment: `$('#btnSave').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });` tried this?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Thanks that worked as it should! I did as you suggested and put the type on my button.